# how do I fix this error?

Tags: apt, ppa, directory

```
dion@dion-Lenovo-ideapad-330S-15IKB:~$ apt install update
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: You are not running `apt` as superuser (using `sudo`). Also, `update` is not a valid package name. Maybe you want to `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: `E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` suggests that you made a serious mistake or typo trying to add that source. Delete that line from your source, and add the source again more carefully.

Comment: what source are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

Read the last line of errors:

```
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Are you root ?
No, you are not, you have to run the command as:

```
sudo apt install update
```

to havw root / administrative rights.